BUSCAR HORA EN UN RANGO DE HORAS
tengo un hoja de excel en la cual necesito que se compare una hora en un rango de horas y pero a su vez las horas se condicionan por fecha; tengo un libro en el cual tengo dos tablas; necesito buscar la hora del la tabla de la izquierda (Tabla A) en el rango de horas de la tabla de la derecha(tabla B) donde se puede ver la columna F (hora de inicio) y la columna G (hora de fin) y que si lo encuentra me devuelva en el estado Si, caso contrario NO.
El proceso que deseo es el siguiente:

Que compare la fecha de la tabla A en la tabla B
Si lo encuentra que busque la hora de la tabla A por ejemplo la celda B2 en el rango de la fecha sería F2 a G2, si esta en ese rango devuelva en el estado SI
Si no lo encuentra que nuevamente compare la fecha A2 = E2 si es igual compare la hora B2 en el rango F3 a G3 y asi en todo el cuadro.

Resumiento:
A2 = E2 si? entonces
B2 se encuentra en el rango F2 - G2; no? sigue el proceso
B2 se encuentra en el rango F3 - G3; no? sigue el proceso
B2 se encuentra en el rango F4 - G4; no? sigue el proceso
B2 se encuentra en el rango F5 - G5; no? sigue el proceso
B2 se encuentra en el rango F6 - G6; no? sigue el proceso
B2 se encuentra en el rango F7 - G7; no? sigue el proceso
devuelve en el estado NO
A3 = E2 si? entonces
B3 se encuentra en el rango F2 - G2; Si? sigue el proceso
devuelve en el estado SI
Este es el código que tengo avanzado, el problema que tengo es que cuando no encuentra la coincidencia de la fecha por el Exit for que le puse sale del segundo for y su valor vuelve a hacer 2; aun no se como puedo hacer que cuando no encuentre la fecha por ejemplo 01/05/2024 este busque la siguiente fecha.
Public Sub Buscar()
Dim uFila3, uFila4 As Long
Dim i3, i4, a, b, c, Med As Variant

uFila3 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
uFila4 = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i3 = 2 To uFila3
    For i4 = 2 To uFila4

    
       `a = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i3).Value
        b = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i4).Value
        c = ActiveSheet.Range("L" & i4).Value
        
        If ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i3).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & i4).Value Then
            Med = WorksheetFunction.Median(a, b, c)
            If ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i3) = Med Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i3) = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & i4).Value
                Exit For
            End If
            
            MsgBox "bien " & "C" & i3 & " VS " & "I" & i4
            
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i3).Value <> ActiveSheet.Range("I" & i4).Value Then
            Exit For
            MsgBox "Mal " & "C" & i3 & " VS " & "I" & i4
        
            End If
    Next i4
Next i3


        


